# Segmentation fault allocating memory with struct of struct

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc, calloc

i am quite new using allocate memory and pointers,

my idea is try to create a struct inside a struct in order to use them after in the code, however far now i obtained a segmentation fault error that i cannot manage.
Thank you for any help

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{

int nb;
double i8,i9,i10;

struct vect3d1
{
        double *x,*y,*z;
};

struct block
{
        int ibl;
        int i,j,k;
        struct vect3d1 *mesh;

};


struct block *blocks;

i8=8.0;


nb=2;
blocks=(struct block *)malloc(nb*sizeof(struct block));

for(int i=0;i<nb;i++){

blocks[i].ibl=i;
blocks[i].mesh->x = calloc(1,sizeof(double));
blocks[i].mesh->x = &i8;
```

}
}

Comment: `blocks[i].mesh->x = &i8;` has overwritten the pointer to the memory allocation just returned by `calloc`. It's unclear what you are trying to do by allocating memory which is enough for only one `double` variable.

Comment: i am trying to assign the variable.

Comment: Try `*blocks[i].mesh->x = i8;`

Comment: Which variable? `x` inside `strut vect3d1` is a _pointer_. It _points_ to a variable, but is a variable itself (has a value). `blocks[i].mesh->x = calloc(1,sizeof(double));` allocates memory for a single double variable and stores the pointer value inside the `blocks[i].mesh->x` vairable. You can modify the _memory_ by using the * operator, like `*blocks[i].mesh->x  = 0.5`.

Comment: @WeatherVane it gives segmentation fault as well

Comment: My comment agrees with the one from Kamil. Did you copy it correctly?

Comment: Initially not, sorry. I have modified my previous comment. It gives again segmentation fault.

Comment: You have not allocated any memory for `struct vect3d1 *mesh`

Comment: Do you need `mesh` to be a pointer?  Structures can contain other structures directly if that would serve your purpose.  There are several reasons why it might not, but none of them are evident in the code presented.

Answer (score 1):

The reason for the seg fault is because you are dereferencing uninitialized pointer `blocks[i].mesh`. The address in `mesh` member is unknown as `malloc` returns uninitialized memory (`mesh` got it's value from memory allocated using the `malloc` of the `block`) and dereferencing such pointer is undefined behavior.

Quoting C11, chapter §7.22.3.5, The malloc function:

> The malloc function allocates space for an object whose size is
>   specified by size and whose value is indeterminate.

Quoting C11, annex §J.2, Undefined behavior:

> The value of the object allocated by the malloc function is used

Comment: Thank you for your help, i am sorry but i am not sure to understand properly. I have to allocate memory also for mesh? Why? malloc for block is not enough?

Comment: `mesh` is a pointer inside `block`. When you allocate space for `block` you allocate just enough space for the `block` structure, which includes `int ibl`, `int i,j,k` and the pointer `struct vect3d1 *mesh`, so `mesh` (along with `ibl`, `i`, `j`, `k`) contains indeterminate value. And what would happen if you deference a pointer with indeterminate value? only god knows. So you need to allocate memory of size `struct vect3d1` and put the address in `mesh`. so `mesh = (struct vect3d1 *)malloc(sizeof (struct vect3d1))`